# Numpy collapse/max, but compare at specific index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to collapse an array along a given dimension by comparing the elements at a specific index and keeping the elements in the dimension where the value at that index was highest.

For example, if the first dimension in the example below is divided into two 2D arrays A and B, I want `A[1,i] >= B[1,i] => RES[:,i] = A[:,i]` for all column-indices(i):

```py
A = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
               [0, 1, 2, 1]],
              [[5, 6, 7, 8],
               [1, 0, 3, 1]]])
np.amax(A, axis=??)
# Desired output:
[[5, 2, 7, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 1]]
```

Is there any numpy functions that can do this?

Edit:
How can I do this if the array have a larger number of elements?:

```py
B = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
               [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
               [ 0,  1,  2,  1]],
              [[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15, 16],
               [ 1,  0,  3,  1]],
              [[17, 18, 19, 20],
               [21, 22, 23, 24],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  2]]])
# Desired output:
[[ 9, 2, 11, 20],
 [13, 6, 15, 24],
 [ 1, 1,  3,  2]]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I read this as you have two 2d arrays that you want to collapse into one 2d array, by taking columns from one or the other array depending on a condition. I'm trying to understand what the condition is though. For example, why do you want to take the (2,1)^T column from the first matrix instead of the (6,0)^T column from the second matrix?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the warm welcome! I want the (2,1)^T column because 1 > 0. In other words, I want to pick the values based on the comparison at the 2nd row in each array. In my "actual" problem I have a 4D array I want to collapse down to three dimensions, but I think @quang-hoang 's answer will work for that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cleaner with `np.where` for this:

```
np.where((A[0,1] > A[1,1]), A[0], A[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Well, almost - if I have an arbitrary number of maps, how can I generalize the first selector?